# Google Analytics: incorrect number of sessions when grouping by Custom Dimension

Tags: session, google-analytics

For a while I have successfully queried the number of sessions for my website, including the number of sessions per 'Lang Code' and per 'Distribution Channel'; both Custom Dimensions I have created in Analytics with their own slot and their Scope Type set to 'Session'.

Recently the number of sessions has decreased significantly when I group by a Custom Dimension, e.g. Lang Code.

The following query gives me a number of say 900:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-10-17&end-date=2015-10-17&metrics=ga%3Asessions

Whereas this query gives returns around a quarter of that, say ~220:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-10-17&end-date=2015-10-17&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3Adimension14

Now, my initial reaction was that 'Lang Code' was not set on all pages but I checked and this data is includes guaranteed on all pages of my website.

Also, no changes have been made to the Analytics View I'm querying.

The same issue occurred a couple of weeks ago and at the time I fixed this by changing the Scope Type of said Custom Dimensions to Session, but now I'm no longer sure if this was the correct fix or if this was just a temporary glitch since:

- the issue didn't occur before
- the issue now reoccurs

Does anyone have any idea what may have caused this data discrepancy?

P.S. to make things stranger, for daily reporting we run this query every night (around 2am), and then the numbers are actually correct, so apparently it makes a difference at what time the query is executed?

Comment: Are you running the query for the previous day at 2am (in which time zone?) For non-premium accounts its usually safest to import data after midnight PST, so around 4am CET for me.

Comment: The timezone we're in is UTC+02:00, we started logging the numbers per hour this week and have noticed a drop around 5am - 6am in the numbers, so we found out the time of importing does matter indeed!